# How can I display Latex style font using Jupyter Notebook Extension in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I am doing my homework using Jupyter Notebook Extension and Sympy module of Python in VS Code. I am trying to render equations in Latex font, but it does not work as I imagined. Is there anybody who can guess what the problem would be? I have added captured images related to the problem.

I am using

- VS Code 1.52
- Jupyter Notebook Extension v2020.12.414227025
- Python Extension v2020.11.371526539

Thank you and have a nice Sunday!

When I type random equation like below, it is displayed in this style

[image]

However when I type in certain equation that I found online, then it is displayed in proper Latex font.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct LaTeX output for that expression. That is the result of the integral displayed in terms of the hypergeometric function:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function

You might not recognise the function but it is an ordinary mathematical function and you can substitute values into is and evaluate it etc:

```
In [17]: antiderivative = integrate(Si(x)/x, x)

In [18]: antiderivative
Out[18]: 
       ⎛              │   2 ⎞
   ┌─  ⎜   1/2, 1/2   │ -x  ⎟
x⋅ ├─  ⎜              │ ────⎟
  2╵ 3 ⎝3/2, 3/2, 3/2 │  4  ⎠

In [19]: antiderivative.subs(x, 1)
Out[19]: 
 ┌─  ⎛   1/2, 1/2   │     ⎞
 ├─  ⎜              │ -1/4⎟
2╵ 3 ⎝3/2, 3/2, 3/2 │     ⎠

In [20]: antiderivative.subs(x, 1).n()
Out[20]: 0.981810799391358
```

Many ordinary looking mathematical functions can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions and sometimes it is possible to simplify them into something more recognisable:

```
In [27]: hyper([], [S(1)/2], -x**2/4)
Out[27]: 
     ⎛    │   2 ⎞
 ┌─  ⎜    │ -x  ⎟
 ├─  ⎜    │ ────⎟
0╵ 1 ⎝1/2 │  4  ⎠

In [28]: hyperexpand(_)
Out[28]: cos(x)
```

It is useful to be able to rewrite an integral in terms of hypergeometric functions because a routine that can integrate hypergeometric functions can work for a wide variety of possible integrands. It is particularly use for special functions (such as `Si`) without needing special rules for each new function that we might want to integrate. SymPy has a specific integration routine `meijerg` which does this using the even more general Meijer G function:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function

SymPy has used the `meijerg` routine for this integral although it looks like the result has been converted to hypergeometric functions rather than G functions. Sometimes it is possible to simplify the result of a definite integral even if it is computed using an antiderivative that can only be expressed in terms of hypergeometric/G functions.

In the case of this integral though it doesn't look like SymPy can express it using other functions. I checked WolframAlpha as well which gives a less simple (but equivalent) representation in terms of hypergeometric functions as well:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+Si%28x%29%2Fx

Comment: Oh of course! I should have looked more carefully

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you've got two different types of output (Unicode and LaTeX), but I can tell you how you can be sure that the LaTeX rendering is the unfailing default

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex=True)
...
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it does not work either ;( But thanks guys for your kind helps guys!!